Accessing Preview Mode for Pages With Query Strings in URL
Using Sitecore CMS 9.2
My apologies if this description wanders, but I'm not sure whether I've got 1 problem or 2, as I get different exceptions on the same pages in different environments.
In our pre-release environments certain pages generate a "potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client" exception when trying to open them in Preview modes.  The pages in question include a query string in their URLs (used to select content to populate), which appears to conflict with the generation of the preview URL (which also has a query string), resulting in a URL with a '&' but no '?' character.
In our production environment, the same pages throw the "Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent" exception.  I'm unclear whether this is a different manifestation of the same problem or a completely different exception being generated from a different part of the process (the more so since the internet indicates a lot of different scenarios which can generate this exception).  Is this likely to be the same problem - that is, is there a single known condition which might generate either of these exceptions in slightly different conditions - or should I pursue them separately?
One additional question:  we're working towards upgrading from Sitecore 9.2 to Sitecore 10 fairly soon.  Is that likely to affect the problem(s)?

How do you generate urls for those pages?

Can you please describe the scenario leading up to the exception and also any code being used to redirect etc

I believe both the issues should be looked separately. One of the issue for potentially dangerous request.path was detected, occurs due to the settings of requestPathInvalidCharacters and requestValidationMode set inside httpruntime section inside Web.config.
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />

Other issue for server cannot modify cookies after http headers were sent, occurs due to some redirection at code level, which are not done correctly. When calling HttpResponse.Redirect, we should call below code before performing redirect.
 HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
 HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("", true);

More details for the same can be found here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms526001(v=vs.90)
Hope this helps!!!

There was, indeed, a redirect occurring, but adding the Flush() and CompleteRequest() calls didn't help - I still get the Cannot Modify Cookies exception.  (I finally managed to catch it throwing that before it throws the Potentially Dangerous Request Path, so I'm focusing on Cannot Modify Cookies first.)

@RonRitchie can you try buffering output as above before doing redirection. Hope this helps!!!

This seems to have fixed the Cannot Modify Cookies exception in as much as I'm no longer capturing that in my debugger.  I'm still getting the Potentially Dangerous Path exception locally, though, which is blocking me from positively confirming it.

@RonRitchie any particluar url you can share, in which you are getting potentially dangerous Request.Path was detected error?
